# How to manipulate the height of a ProMotion::Table::Cell

Tags: rubymotion

Im quite new to rubymotion and Promotion so sorry if the question is a stupid one :) I can't find any information how to manipulate a height of a cell after clicking on it. Somebody knows how to do this? Thanks a lot

```
class TimeOffsScreen < ProMotion::TableScreen

  def table_data
    TimeItem.all.map do |item|
      {
        title: item.name,
        action: :open_time_item,
        arguments: { item: item },
        editing_style: :delete,
        height: 90
      }
    end
  end

  def open_time_item(item)
    # Set height of this table cell
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this currently. One way you can accomplish it is to access the data in your hash and then refresh the table data.

By the way, I noticed a bug in your code. You need to provide an array of sections wrapping your cells.

I've put an example of how to do this here, but you'll need to verify that it does work.

```
def table_data
  @time_items ||= TimeItem.all
  [{
    cells: @time_items.map do |item|
      { 
        title: item.name,
        action: :open_time_item,
        arguments: { item: item },
        editing_style: :delete,
        height: item.height || 90
      }
    end
  }]
end

def open_time_item(item)
  item.height = 180 # .height can be a temporary attr_accessor with no persistence
  update_table_data
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jamon! It is working. Thanks for the bug as well! The bug wasnt in my actual code, I stripped it down for this example. One quick question if I may, Is it possible to make it bigger with an animation as well? I was trying to get the TableCell instance in the open_time_item method. I guess I can't use Promotion for this? A big Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. The problem of animation isn't really anything ProMotion-specific. You'll need to detect a touch on your UITableViewCell and then run your animations from there. One possible way to do this would be to use [RMQ](http://infinitered.com/rmq/) to bind events to your cells and animate them.